# Use switch statement for identifying type of instance of object - not working

Tags: javascript

I tried to follow [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332665/how-to-use-instanceof-in-a-switch-statement).

```js
var Animal = function(){}

var Dog = function(){}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

var dog = new Dog();

switch(dog.constructor){
    case Dog:
        console.log("Good Dog")
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Bad Dog");
}
```

It logs "Bad Dog".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `dog instanceof Dog`

Comment: @Deryck In that case `dog instanceof dog` and `dog instanceof Animal` both will yield true result.

Comment: @Ayan ...that's why it's in the order of `Dog` then `default`.  It won't be an `instanceof Dog` if it's only an `Animal`.

Answer (score 2):

The contructor reference is getting overridden due to the prototypal inheritance. Check the logs in the below snippet.

```js
var Animal = function() {}
Animal.prototype.disp = function () {
  return 'I am an Animal';
}
var Dog = function() {}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

var someOtherAnimal = new Dog();
// On inheriting the prototypal chain, the constructor is overridden.
console.log(someOtherAnimal.constructor === Animal);
// over riding the constructor
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

var someAnimal = new Dog();
console.log(someAnimal.constructor === Dog);

switch (someAnimal.constructor) {
  case Dog:
    console.log("Good Dog")
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Bad Dog");
}
// access the animal prototpe.
console.log(someAnimal.disp());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using setting `Dog`'s prototype to a new instance of `Animal.prototype` overrides `Dog`'s constructor. That's why a typical inheritance pattern is.

```
var Foo = function () {};
var Bar = function () {};
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

In your current code `Dog.constructor === Animal`. Modifying it as above will give you the behavior you desire.

Comment: Ah great, thanks. Are there any side effects of doing this? Will it change behaviour in any circumstances? I.e. when setting `Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar`, is that property ever used in any way, other than if I were to use it in a switch statement?

Comment: @Jodes Your code will likely not work the way you expect the way it is currently written. The `new` operator will actually call the constructor of `Animal`, not `Dog`. That's because when you override `Dog`'s prototype with the `Object.create`, it also overrides its constructor. That's why you need to set `Dog`'s constructor back to itself. I would read up more on JavaScript's [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) if that was confusing to you - it can be tricky to get the hang of. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

```
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

The Object to create seems to give the Dog class the type of Object class. There is a way to determine a class name for an object by

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
```

It returns a string in the following format: '[object ' + valueOfClass + ']', e.g [object String] or [object Array]. In your case instead of returning Dog class, it was returning Object class due to the topmost line overriding your Dog class.

For preserving inheritance of Animal class into Dog Class and getting the desired result as per Harangue answer, putting the line below inheritance.

```
 Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
 Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byaqbuue/3/

Comment: This would remove the inheritance of `Dog` from `Animal` which seems to be a requirement in the question.