# How to Load fragment according to it's instance at runtime using polymorphism?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, switch-statement

I have a tab layout with 3 tab items each having its own fragment to load at runtime when selected.

**MainActivity.class:** Here call to LoadFragment according to position of selected tab.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        LoadFragment(new LocationFragment());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        LoadFragment(new InformationFragment());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        LoadFragment(new CommentsFragment());
                        break;
                }
            }
```

My question is how can I use **switch** statement for the logic to load proper fragment using fragment manager? I don't want to have **if else** statement hierarchy.

```
private void LoadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (*some logic here*) {

            case fragment instanceof LocationFragment:
                Log.i("MainActivity", "inside load fragment");
                ft.replace(R.id.coordinate_layout, new LocationFragment());
                break;


            case fragment instanceof InformationFragment:
                ft.replace(R.id.coordinate_layout, new InformationFragment());
                break;


            case fragment instanceof CommentsFragment:
                ft.replace(R.id.coordinate_layout, new CommentsFragment());
                break;

            ft.commit();

        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by an inside switch (*some logic here*)

Comment: are you using view pager with tab layout>

Comment: @GaneshGudghe logic like in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286277/7805408) but in java boolean is not accepted by switch

Comment: @Avinash I am not using viewpager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Don't need to create instances multiple times, you can simply pass the type and while loading you can decide which fragment you need to load.

```
    private static final int TYPE_LOCATION=0;
    private static final int TYPE_INFO=1;
    private static final int TYPE_COMMENT=2;

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        LoadFragment(TYPE_LOCATION);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        LoadFragment(TYPE_INFO);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        LoadFragment(TYPE_COMMENT);
                        break;
                }
            }

private void LoadFragment(int typeOfFragment) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "inside load fragment");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (typeOfFragment) {

            case TYPE_LOCATION:   
              ft.replace(R.id.coordinate_layout, new LocationFragment());
                break;


            case TYPE_INFO:
                ft.replace(R.id.coordinate_layout, new InformationFragment());
                break;


            case TYPE_COMMENT:
                ft.replace(R.id.coordinate_layout, new CommentsFragment());
                break;

            ft.commit();

        }
    }
```