# determine type of parameter that could have multiple types in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards

Given a function with a parameter of different types, how do I find out which type was passed to the function?

Example

```
interface SomeCustomInterface {
    title: string
}

interface OtherCustomInterface {
    subtitle: string
}


interface A {
    value: string
}

interface B {
    value: number
}

interface C {
    value: SomeCustomInterface
}

interface D {
    value: OtherCustomInterface
}

function doSomething(parameter: A | B | C | D): string {
    switch(parameter.type) { 
        // I know the cases are not valid TS. What should I do instead?
        case A:
            return parameter.value
        case B:
            return parameter.value.toString()
        case C:
            return parameter.value.title
        case D:
            return parameter.value.subtitle
    }
}
```

I know that there are type guards but I have concerns with those

1. They need to be able to uniquely identify each type. I see that some people add a property `kind` or `type` which allows them to identify a type in order to type guard it. This seems like a lot of overhead and boilerplate to me though.
2. You need to write a custom function for each type like `type is A` or `type is B` which again would lead to massive overhead in my context.

What is the appropriate way to approach this in typescript?

Comment: Would comparing the type be enough? i.e. `parameter.value` being a `number`, `string` or `object`. If so, you could always use `typeof`?

Comment: It might also be different types of objects. I updated my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript)

Comment: I looked into this possibility but saw that it would create a lot of overhead. All the properties are named `value` so even if I create the 4 extra `isA`, `isB`, `isC`, `isD` methods I would still need to inspect the `value` for `isSomeCustomType` and `isOtherCustomType` and with this cascading requirement it would add too much overhead to support it in my project.

Comment: Why don't you check the typeof the parameter? You don't really need to access it's members for this.

Comment: Nevermind. I suppose this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332665/how-to-use-instanceof-in-a-switch-statement) answers yours to some extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there are only 2 options as described in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript).

> What you can do is check that the shape of an object is what you expect, and TypeScript can assert the type at compile time using a user-defined type guard that returns true (annotated return type is a "type predicate" of the form arg is T) if the shape matches your expectation:

> For class types you can use JavaScript's `instanceof` to determine the class an instance comes from, and TypeScript will narrow the type in the type-checker automatically.

A side note from myself:

If you have the same propertyname you can potentially refactor your code using generics, like:

```
interface A {
    value: string
}

interface B {
    value: number
}

interface C {
    value: SomeCustomInterface
}

interface D {
    value: OtherCustomInterface
}
```

can be

```
interface GenericInterface<T>{
 value: T
}
```

Comment: Using classes feels superior to me. They come with typechecks out of the box that don't rely on the shape and as far as I understand they are just plain JS objects at runtime.