# Receiving "Property 'message' does not exist on type 'object'" although I am doing the necessary type checking

Tags: typescript

I am having the following code:

```
try {
 // api call
} catch (error) {
  if (typeof error === 'object' && error !== null && 'message' in error) {
    if (typeof error.message === 'string') {
      if (error.message.match(userRejectedError)) {
        // do stuff
      } else {
        // do other stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error: `Property 'message' does not exist on type 'object'`.
Why? I am clearly checking all types needed.

Edit:
TSConfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    },
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't happen to me [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4JwngBA3gUBEHoEQIYAcCWEDGKA2eMAvjisNgBYQAUApiCAPYgCU0cEGAZjcGGrUY96TEBAC8kiAHJGAIwBWtbMGkQAZOogjmEAIRSAdgFcCGrdIC2tAM42UAc1pqMh7Q2ZtY8eN179BYQ8QADprO0daCSlpG1BXB2kvDh9OHjpgsNt7JzCySmoEABMEFmTU1KQIIsYIOOMuLhSfElo8GyjvCvgqmohGYAp6OuAGpu6iZsn4ScmgA). Can you share a playground with your tsconfig applied?

Comment: @wonderflame updated my OP with the tsconfig. The weird thing is, in my VSCode it does not moan about the linter either. However when running linting, it does.

Comment: I still can't reproduce:(. Could you make a typescript playground?

Comment: @wonderflame I found the issue. It was due to an older version of TS that didn't support the in operator for checking unknown properties.

Comment: glad to hear that, let's then close the question

Answer (score 0):

### You are not checking type strictly

You are currently just checking that `error` instance is object, not null, have `message` as property, and `error.message`'s type name is `string`, rather than just check `error` instance is `Error` type.

use `instanceof` keyword to check type, not `typeof` compare with string.

if you can guarantee that `error` instance is type `Error`, then ts can surely know that instance have property `message`.

for example:

```js
try{
/* some error-throwable code... */
} catch(error) {
  /* Use instanceof to compare between instance - type */
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    // Do stuff
  }
  /* Or you can use switch clause */
  switch (error.constructor) {
    case Error:
      // Do stuff
  }
}
```

below link is type document of `Error`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: plus. in switch clause, `.constructor` property only returns true when type is exactly same,  no inheritance compare allowed, while instanceof can do.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332665/how-to-use-instanceof-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: the error is not always instance of `Error`.

Comment: Then, you can add more if/case in bottom to check that type explicitly...

Comment: or, What you want is just to guarentee that `error` instance has property `message` and it's type is `string`?

Comment: Correct. I want the above code to not throw an error in my linter without coercing types.

Comment: Then sorry that I can't help anything since I can't reproduce error...